# Unity app works on development build, not on normal one

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I created a very simple RSS feed reader. For now, it's very basic. One problem I've encountered is that the app doesn't work on Android unless it's development build.

The RSS feed should output the feed as GUI. It does that in Unity Editor and in PC build. But, it works on Android build only if it is set as development build, otherwise it just shows the "RSS Reader" label that's hard coded as GUI.

There are no errors, it doesn't crash or freeze, which is really odd.

I think the problem is in setup time. When I make the setup take more time, it works even without development build. But I'm not sure what the actual problem is that causes this.

Here is the relevant script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Xml;

public class rsstester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject newsItemObject;

    XmlTextReader rssReader;
    XmlDocument rssDoc;

    string feedUrl = "http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews?format=xml";

    void Start() {
        rssReader = new XmlTextReader (feedUrl);
        rssDoc = new XmlDocument ();
        rssDoc.Load (rssReader);

        XmlNode rssNode = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < rssDoc.ChildNodes.Count; i++) {
            XmlNode childNode = rssDoc.ChildNodes [i];
            if (childNode.Name == "rss") {
                rssNode = childNode;
                break;
            }
        }

        XmlNode channelNode = null;

        if (rssNode != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rssNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++) {
                XmlNode childNode = rssNode.ChildNodes [i];

                if (childNode.Name == "channel") {
                    channelNode = childNode;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        List<XmlNode> newsItems = new List<XmlNode> ();

        if (channelNode != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < channelNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++) {
                XmlNode childNode = channelNode.ChildNodes [i];

                if (childNode.Name == "item") {
                    newsItems.Add (childNode);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (XmlNode newsItem in newsItems) {
            string title = newsItem ["title"].InnerText;
            string description = newsItem ["description"].InnerText;
            string link = newsItem ["link"].InnerText;

            GameObject childObject = Instantiate(newsItemObject) as GameObject;
            childObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform, false);

            childObject.transform.Find ("Title").gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = title;
            childObject.transform.Find ("Title").gameObject.GetComponent<LinkClick> ().link = link;
            childObject.transform.Find ("Description").gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [unity package](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhneTdGMllqeTVjSEk&export=download)

Here are the APKs:

- ARMv7

  - [Normal](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhnX2loT09DZ0dZbDA&export=download) (~11MB)
  - [Dev](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhnV1lrS2JYbWRiYnM&export=download) (~14MB)
- x86

  - [Normal](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhndlk3TlIxcVF4UVU&export=download) (~12MB)
  - [Dev](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhnNGFZNE5tYlllLUU&export=download) (~14MB)
- FAT (ARMv7 + x86)

  - [Normal](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhnMGhROXVuNmk1V1k&export=download) (~20MB)
  - [Dev](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhnc25OX1VXd2c4Skk&export=download) (~24MB)

**Edit**:

> Assets will often include AndroidManifest. Are you sure that this is not related with permissions?

It doesn't seem to have anything close to that. No `.xml` files at all. Oddly enough, the app works when I only import the C# files from the package.

Here is the [unity package](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B8lPhuqvdZhnWGtMU01wOE1zYUE&export=download) with the scripts and here are the C# files themselves: [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8lPhuqvdZhnQkxvVmg2TUNGeFk/view?usp=sharing) [2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8lPhuqvdZhnMmUyLW51U21CUUk/view?usp=sharing) [3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8lPhuqvdZhnQ2JLTXpvTVpPelE/view?usp=sharing) [4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8lPhuqvdZhncDFqdG9HUGw2bjQ/view?usp=sharing)

**Edit #2**:

After some trial and error, I found out which file is needed to make the app work. I have no clue how this can be possible.

Here it is: [Reporter.cs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8lPhuqvdZhnZ2UzdENTQ1BVUnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You haven't explained what you mean by "doesn't work". Does it produce an error? Does it crash? 

I'm guessing that you're suggesting that it's slow to startup and gets quit by the OS for being unresponsive? If that's the case, I'd suggest you're trying to do too much work in Start() and you should spread it across multiple frames. Unity's Coroutine system is an easy way to achieve this with minimal code changes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize I didn't actually post what exactly is wrong. The RSS feed should output the feed as GUI. It does that in Unity Editor, PC build. It works on Android build only if it is development build, otherwise it just shows the "RSS Reader" label that's hard coded as GUI.

Comment: Can you try doing the build without striping code?

Comment: @JerrySwitalski What do you mean?

Comment: In build settings options you will have strip engine code option to check, or even more (I am not sure as on my current Unity3D I don't have android module). Maybe this striping strips a little to much so it won't work on release build. I believe that development build doesn't strip code.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Ok I'll try that

Comment: Oh, I have `Stripping level` set to `Disabled`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c4d3iu

Comment: I see, then it is not a problem. To be honest I have no idea what could be the problem. I think it is worth trying research what are exactly differences between dev and release builds for android in Unity3D and look for the problem there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120697/discussion-between-slayther-and-jerry-switalski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, apps requires permissions. You app uses internet connection to download data so you need to add following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Development version works because in manifest there are additional lines added by Unity, which of course are missing in production version:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="18" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To add manifest in Unity create a file `AndroidManifest.xml` in `{Project root}\Assets\Plugins\Android` and then paste this manifest (it yours from production version with additional permission added):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.slayther_and_malekian.rss_reader" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2704002">
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
        <application android:banner="@drawable/app_banner" android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:isGame="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <activity android:configChanges="locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>
            </activity>
        </application>
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false"/>
    </manifest>
```

Or you can use magic trick which causes Unity to add permission by itself. Put this code anywhere in the project.

```
WWW magic = new WWW("magic");
```

Comment: Well, it's not a problem with permissions. _When I make the setup take more time, it works even without development build. But I'm not sure what the actual problem is that causes this._ I can get the app to work without development build if I import random asset that is big enough.

Comment: Assets will often include AndroidManifest. Are you sure that this is not related with permissions?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything close to that. No `.xml` files at all. It has a lot of images, though. I will try to import only the images and see if the app works without dev build then. **Edit:** No, it doesn't work. So it seems it does have some files that are needed and contain the permissions. Oddly enough, it only contains C# files now.

Comment: Look the C# code you import uses WWW from Unity. So Unity automaticly adds `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the manifest. I checked that by apktool. I did my tests (I copied your code) and without manually added manifest I was getting `WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure`. I was getting the same error on your .apk. Download apktool run it as `apktool d myapk.apk` and it will create folder with source, manifest will be there and check if it has permission.

Comment: But how can the app work without the manifest in my case? It works good even when I only left 1 C# file from the package, the `Reporter.cs`. I fixed all compile errors by commenting out code that included the other scripts' namespaces. When I delete the file and build and run, it doesn't work. It works with it.

Comment: Add this magic line `WWW www = new WWW("magic");` before xml (but it should work everywhere). It should do magic. To answer your question `Reporter.cs` is the file that has WWW inside it. Now I think I just didn't explain how to exactly put AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Oh, I missed when you said "_code **you import** uses WWW_". Adding `WWW www = new WWW("magic");` did the trick. Thank you very much and sorry for not realizing this before.

Comment: Could you reward this answer with bounty of this question? I also edit the post (magic trick and better AndroidManifest location)

Comment: I must wait 20 more hours. That's when you will get the bounty ;)